# how to HttpRequest for Google Translator with Java only?

Tags: java, httpwebrequest

```
http://translate.google.nl/#en/nl/experiment%20translator
```

How can I request this http. and return the outcome of the translator?
I can't use any external API. So how do I make contact to this url and return it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251510/java-url-google-translate-request-returns-403-error